# 11.1 volt motor in a 12 volt system

Tags: power-supply

I am working with Dynamixel smart servos and most of them have no issue with 12 volts power. I am looking at buying a new addition to my project which seems to want no more than 11.1 volts (ideally). This project ( a robotic arm) will eventually probably work off battery power, occasionally. I need to find a lightweight circuit to reduce my voltage for this motor. What is the best way to do this efficiently and not heavy in weight  (the circuit will sit on the arm, ideally) ?

Comment: Please provide a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for the motor, and not a link to the vendor website.

Comment: _"I am looking at buying a new addition"_ - which servo are you looking at? _"...which **seems to want no more than 11.1 volts** (ideally)"_ - how did you determine that?

Comment: I have bought a handful of dynamixels and they typically take 12 volts without issue. The company recently introduced a 2 axis smart servo that specifically says 12 volt max, 11.1 recommended. I suspect this is to keep it from overheating and shutting down. Here is the data from the manufacturer:

https://www.robotis.us/dynamixel-2xl430-w250-t/